Driving SH8601 OLED display
I have purchased an OLED display based on SH8601 driver IC. But I didn't get any support for driving the display or any source code.
I was left with a initialization code provided by the vendor.

R2A 00 00 01 6F
R2B 00 00 01 BF
R44 01 BF
R36 02
R35 00
R3A 55
R53 20  //DispColor(WHITE      //RC0 5A 5A  //RBA 0x81
//UCS R11,0x00  Delayms(5
Delayms(50
R29  00

I have tried the sh8601_LCD ESP32 component,
sh8601_LCD ESP32
but yet got no results.

What board are you using? Arduino UNO?

Iam using ESP32 board

Did you check here? https://components.espressif.com/components/espressif/esp_lcd_sh8601

Yes I have. but this code's not working. is there anything I need to do to with that initialization code provided by the vendor?
